# Quorum nodes run fine with docker-compose, but crash when deployed on kubernetes

Tags: quorum, docker, aws

Following the steps outlined [here](https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/latest/Tutorials/Create-IBFT-Network/), I created a basic Quorum network with 4 nodes and IBFT consensus. I then created a docker image for each of the nodes, copying the contents of each node's directory on to the image. The image was created from the official `quorumengineering/quorum` image, and when started as a container it executes the geth command. An example Dockerfile follows (different nodes have different rpcports/ports):

```
FROM quorumengineering/quorum
WORKDIR /opt/node
COPY . /opt/node
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore nohup geth --datadir data --nodiscover --istanbul.blockperiod 5 --syncmode full --mine --minerthreads 1 --verbosity 5 --networkid 10 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 22001 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,istanbul  --rpcvhosts="*" --emitcheckpoints --port 30304
```

I then made a docker-compose file to run the images.

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  qnode0-data:
  qnode1-data:
  qnode2-data:
  qnode3-data:
services:
  qnode0:
    container_name: qnode0
    image: <myDockerHub>/qnode0
    ports:
      - 22000:22000
      - 30303:30303
    volumes:
      - qnode0-data:/opt/node
  qnode1:
    container_name: qnode1
    image: <myDockerHub>/qnode1
    ports:
      - 22001:22001
      - 30304:30304
    volumes:
      - qnode1-data:/opt/node
  qnode2:
    container_name: qnode2
    image: <myDockerHub>/qnode2
    ports:
      - 22002:22002
      - 30305:30305
    volumes:
      - qnode2-data:/opt/node
  qnode3:
    container_name: qnode3
    image: <myDockerHub>/qnode3
    ports:
      - 22003:22003
      - 30306:30306
    volumes:
      - qnode3-data:/opt/node
```

When running these images locally with docker-compose, the nodes start and I can even see the created blocks via a blockchain explorer. However, when I try to run this in a kubernetes cluster, either locally with minikube, or on AWS, the nodes do not start but rather crash.
To deploy on kubernetes I made the following three yaml files for each node (12 files in total):

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: qnode0
  name: qnode0
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: qnode0
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: qnode0
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <myDockerHub>/qnode0
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: qnode0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 22000
        - containerPort: 30303
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/node
          name: qnode0-data
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - name: qnode0-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: qnode0-data
status: {}
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: qnode0-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: qnode0
  ports:
    - name: rpcport
      protocol: TCP
      port: 22000
      targetPort: 22000
    - name: netlistenport
      protocol: TCP
      port: 30303
      targetPort: 30303
```

persistentvolumeclaim.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: qnode0-data
  name: qnode0-data
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

When trying to run on a kubernetes cluster, each node runs into this error:

```
ERROR[] Cannot start mining without etherbase    err="etherbase must be explicitly specified"
Fatal: Failed to start mining: etherbase missing: etherbase must be explicitly specified
```

which does not occur when running locally with docker-compose. After examining the logs, I saw there is a difference between how the nodes startup locally with docker-compose and on kubernetes, which is the following lines:

locally I see the following lines in each node's output:

```
INFO [] Initialising Ethereum protocol           name=istanbul versions="[99 64]" network=10 dbversion=7
...
DEBUG[] InProc registered                        namespace=istanbul
```

on kubernetes (either in minikube or AWS) I see these lines differently:

```
INFO [] Initialising Ethereum protocol           name=eth versions="[64 63]" network=10 dbversion=7
...
DEBUG[] IPC registered                           namespace=eth
DEBUG[] IPC registered                           namespace=ethash
```

Why is this happening? What is the significance of `name=istanbul/eth`? My common sense logic says that the error happens because of the use of `name=eth`, instead of `name=istanbul`. But I don't know the significance of this, and more importantly, I don't know what it is I did to inadvertently affect the kubernetes deployment.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Generally speaking, its likely that `geth` used in kube on AWS is plain vanilla rather than Quorum build. Is this something that you could verify?

Also, for k8s example setup or simplified configuration, try this project: https://github.com/ConsenSys/qubernetes

Comment: @fixanoid Thanks for the comment. The geth I use is in the docker image ```quorumengineering/quorum```, so I would expect it to be ok. As for qubernetes, it does sound ideal, but uses certain things that I don't need, e.g. Tessera. And it's not clear to me how to use it together with AWS. But I agree, it's something I would like to know more about.

Comment: As said, the initialization seems suspect as the log shows, maybe something else in the starter scripts then? It may be better if you joined our slack so we could debug: https://inviter.quorum.consensys.net/

Comment: Double check you are loading your genesis and node config file right... It seems that it does not detect your consensus engine since you are using istanbul and shows ethash. As @fixanoid mention, If I were you I would check how k8s artifacts are built using the qubernetes package.